# How to test MySQL master-slave replication latency and get the exact time of slave library latency (accurate to milliseconds)

Tags: mysql

How to test MySQL master-slave replication latency, I need to get the exact time of slave library latency (accurate to milliseconds)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Which MySQL version? Is this a generic benchmark? Or are you trying to record this for all replicated data? Why you are doing this will affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO latency (master, slave) VALUES
    (NOW(3),      -- same time on Master and Slave
     SYSDATE(3))   -- time at which this query was run on each
```

Then diff them to see the latency.

Caveats:

- Running with `--sysdate-is-now` would prevent the trick from working.  Test via `SELECT NOW(6), SYSDATE(6);`.
- I have not tested this.
- `SYSDATE` is "unsafe for replication" (but we are taking advantage of that!); however, the `binlog_format` may impact it.

Comment: But slave is read-only. The time `sysdate` to insert the current system into the main library is master's time, and the field in the table of the slave library is master's time too. It is impossible to test master-slave latency.

Comment: @alice.tang - The writes in the replication stream bypass the `read_only` setting.  The definition of `SYSDATE()` is that it actually computes the time _when it is run_; that _should_ be different on the Slave than the Master, at least in Statement Based Replication.  `NOW()`, on the other hand, is carefully engineered to end up the same on the Slave, even after delays.  Please test it.  I don't have a setup handy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the MySQL slow query log: Open your MySQL configuration file (typically located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf) and add the following lines under the [mysqld] section:

`slow_query_log = 1`
`long_query_time = 0`
`log_output = FILE`
`slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log`

2. Restart the MySQL service

   `service mysql restart`
3. Perform a test query on the master database: Connect to the master database and execute a test query that updates a record. For example:

   `mysql -u root -p -e "UPDATE your_table SET column_name = 'test' WHERE id = 1;"`
4. Monitor the slow query log on the slave database

   `tail -f /var/log/mysql/slow-query.log | grep "UPDATE your_table"`